# How to implement re.IGNORECASE method in grep of python-docx

Tags: python, python-re, python-docx

I would like to make grep function with python-docx.

```
from docx import Document

files = glob.glob("Folders/*.docx")
fetchWord = "sample"

for file in files:
    document = Document(file)
    count = 0
    for para in document.paragraphs:
        
        if para.text.find(fetchWord) > -1:
            print(file + ":" + "Line" + str(count) + ":" + para.text)
```

With this code, I can grep only  **"sample"**, but not grep **"Sample"**, **"sAmPle"** and so on.

For grep these words, I would like to implement **re.IGNORECASE** method in the above code.
How do I do this?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Python's `re` module if you want to use `re.IGNORECASE`. If you need to use a regex, then this is the way to go. You can do so like this:

```
import re
from docx import Document

files = glob.glob("Folders/*.docx")
fetchWord = "sample"

for file in files:
    document = Document(file)
    count = 0
    for para in document.paragraphs:
        if re.match(fetchWord, para.text, re.IGNORECASE) != None:
            print(file + ":" + "Line" + str(count) + ":" + para.text)
```

However, if you simply want to search for text and do not need to use a regex, you can use the `.lower()` method to convert the paragraph to lowercase. Like this:

```
from docx import Document

files = glob.glob("Folders/*.docx")
fetchWord = "sample"

for file in files:
    document = Document(file)
    count = 0
    for para in document.paragraphs:
        
        if para.text.lower().find(fetchWord) > -1:
            print(file + ":" + "Line" + str(count) + ":" + para.text)
```

Comment: The `!= None` is redundant.